# Running explorer.exe using Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, runtime, explorer, runtime.exec

I kill explorer.exe using runTime.exec() method and then rerun it in my application. And at the last when i closed my application using system.exit(0); form application closes but java application seems to be run in netbeans' status bar. After i kill the explorer.exe process task manager and rerun it via task manager java application ends.

What is the problem?

Comment: What command(s) are you using to restart explorer.exe?

Comment: 1) For pities sake, start using `ProcessBuilder`! 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).